# Two-finger swipe 'breaks' heads-up notifications on Lollipop?

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop

I have a Nexus 7 (2013) and a Moto X (2014) running Lollipop. On both of these, if I get a heads-up notification (i.e., those that show up on top of the screen when the device is unlocked) and swipe down on it with 2 fingers, it 'breaks' further heads-up notifications:

- I can't tap on them to open the responsible app
- For, e.g., an incoming phone call with 'answer' and 'dismiss' buttons, tapping the buttons does nothing. I can't answer phone calls anymore!

I can still swipe to the side to dismiss the notifications, and they still disappear on their own after a few seconds. I haven't been able to find a way to get the correct behavior back aside from a restart.

Yeah, the obvious workaround is to not two-finger swipe on them, but it's second nature as that same gesture expands notifications in other contexts.

I'm guessing the problem is generic, but I've triggered it on Hangouts and Phone notifications.

Do others experience the same thing? Any known 'fixes' aside from restarting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, and it has been reported on [AOSP Issue Tracker #79583](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79583).

As of current writing, the issue carries on to 5.0.1 Lollipop, reproduced on a Nexus 5. One claimed that the issue has gone on 5.0.1 (but didn't mention the device), and the rest still reported the same issue on it.

If you are interested in the follow-up, you might "star" the issue (I have done it myself).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the bug report - I've starred it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I also posted this in the bug report thread, but if you are rooted, running `pkill systemui` will fix the problem (until the next time you try to do a two-finger swipe).

I created a small APK that runs this command as root (if your phone isn't rooted, I don't think there's any way to restart systemui):
https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95864024717072257